# Bootstrap issue div expands outside of span

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div inside of another div with the "span" class. The child div has width set to 100%. For some reason the div is flowing outside of the parent div.

Adding "overflow: hidden" to the parent only cuts the content off of the child div.

Would anybody know of a solution to this?

Code below

```
.span8 {
float: none;
display: block;
width: 100%;
margin-left: 0;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.child {
padding: 20px;
width: 100%;
}

<div class="span8 clearfix">
    <div class="child">
        My content    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the inner div have any padding? if so you should know that width tryes to ensure "unpadded" space, any padding or borders will cause the div size to increase, eventually overflowing. width:auto on a div should cause it to use as much space as possible without overflowing.

Comment: A `div` is a `block element`, and is not supposed to be inside a `span` which is an `inline element`. This isn't standard and will make you problems.

Comment: Div inside span or div ? Div is a block element. You should show some code ?

Comment: Please make an jsfiddle example.

Comment: Sorry, I should be more clear, I meant to say div with a span class. I will edit above.

Comment: Show your code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `width: 100%` from your child CSS class.

Block elements automatically renders to the full width of their container. Also, when you manually set `width: 100%` with `padding` like you did, it renders like `100% + 40px`.

```
.child {
    padding: 20px;
}

<div class="span8 clearfix">
    <div class="child">
        My content    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I found the problem. I was battling bootstraps span width. I added a class to the span8 and then set the width to 100% like this ".row-fluid .myclass { width: 100% }"

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you did, but again, giving a block element `width: 100%` is not advisable... My solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're supporting IE7, the border-box (http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) method of calculating sizes appears to be a bit easier (less onus on you to do the math). If you place:

```
* { margin:0; padding:0;    
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

at the top of your stylesheet, you'll be free to use it everywhere.